# Olingo Odata4 server : Multiple Primary Key

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I am setting up a basic OData provider using the Olingo OData4 library.

So far, I have two simple entities made of 2 properties where a single element is defined as a key.

```
+--------+    +---------+
| Person |    | Project |
+--------+    +---------+
| ID     |    | CODE    |
| Name   |    | Name    |
+--------+    +---------+
```

I use `propertyRef.setPropertyName("Code")` to specify that Key element, like so:

```
//create EntityType properties
Property code = new Property().setName("Code").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName());
Property name = new Property().setName("Name").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName());

// create PropertyRef for Key element
PropertyRef propertyRef = new PropertyRef();
propertyRef.setPropertyName("Code");

// configure EntityType
EntityType entityType = new EntityType();
entityType.setName(ET_PROJECT_NAME);
entityType.setProperties(Arrays.asList(code, name));
entityType.setKey(Arrays.asList(propertyRef));

return entityType;
```

Now I would like to set up a more complex entity type that has a **set of attributes** as its key element rather that a single Key element.

```
+----------+
| Activity |
+----------+
| pid      | --> FK references (Person.ID)
| pcode    | --> FK references (Project.Code)
| START    |
| END      |
| NAME     |
+----------+
Composite key : {START, END, NAME}
```

According to the documentation, PropertyRef only allows a single String to be passed as argument :
http://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/index.html?org/apache/olingo/ext/proxy/api/annotations/CompoundKey.html

**Questions** :

(1) Is there another class than PropertyRef I should use to register such a composite key?

(2) How to define the two Foreign Keys?

Thanks in advance for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register one PropertyRef per key. So your code should look like this:

```
.setKey(Arrays.asList(
          new CsdlPropertyRef().setName("START"),
          new CsdlPropertyRef().setName("END"))),
          new CsdlPropertyRef().setName("NAME")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs **Olingo4 server** example (integrated with MyBatis and some security is implemented).
It has sqls for database too (for which it is created)

https://github.com/ousatov-ua/Olingo4-server